# HasMany relationship of two child Domain Classes in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, has-many

Good Day to all, I am having an Architecture issue with the way I designed my Domain Class.

I have a parent domain class called **TxnBatch** which has a *One to Many relationship* with Transactions class, and also two other child class **ProcessorTxnBatch** and **TamsTerminalTxnBatch** that extend the **TxnBatch** class

The logic is that when a transaction is being performed, I first add it to **processorTxnBatch.addToTransactions(transactions)**, After the transaction is processed, I then add it to the Terminal Batch **tamsTerminalTxnBatch.addToTransactions(transaction)** which is the other child class

The issue now is that when i add the same transaction to the transactions of another Batch, It removes the Transaction from the former Batch I added it to.

Parent Class

```
  package com.itex.cipg

  class TxnBatch implements Serializable{

static final String OPEN = "OPEN"
static final String CLOSED = "CLOSED"

/**
 *The Batch number of this Transaction
 **Set when the Batch is created
 **/
String batchNo = "0"

 /**
 *The Batch Status of the transaction
 **/
String batchStatus = OPEN
/**
 *The Time this batch was started
 **/
Date startTime
/**
 *The Time this batch was Closed
 **/
 Date lastUpdated
/**
 *The Time this batch was Closed
 **/
Date closeTime
/**
 *The NextSequence Number of this Batch
 **/
Integer seqNo = 1

//Attributes Updated During a payService.updateBatch() Function call in payService
/**
 * The Total Amount of All Transactions
 */
double allTransactionsSum = 0

/**
 * The Total Amount Charged for the Approved Transactions
 */
double approvedTransactionsCharge = 0

/**
 * The Total Amount of Approved Transactions
 */
double approvedTransactionsSum = 0

/**
 * The Total Amount of Declined Transactions
 */
double declinedTransactionsSum = 0

/**
 * The Total Amount of CANCELED Transactions
 */
double canceledTransactionsSum = 0

/**
 * The Total Amount of CANCELED Transactions
 */
double errorTransactionsSum = 0

/**
 * The Total number of ALL Transactions 
 */
int allTransactionsCount = 0

/**
 * The Total number of Approved Transactions
 */
int approvedTransactionsCount= 0

/**
 * The Total number of declined Transactions
 */
int declinedTransactionsCount = 0

/**
 * The Total number of canceled Transactions
 */
int canceledTransactionsCount = 0


/**
*The Total Sum of Unprocessed Transactions
*/
int unProcessedTransactionsSum = 0

/**
*The Total number of Unprocessed Transactions
**/
int unProcessedTransactionsCount = 0

/**
 * The Total number of canceled Transactions
 */
int errorTransactionsCount = 0

/**
*The manimun batch Number to reach before closing this Batch
**/
int  maxBatchNoLimit = 100

static hasMany = [transactions: Transaction]

/**
 *The result of this batch
 *as gotten from TAMS when 
 *the batch is closed
 **/
String result


//Implements the Constraints of this Object
static constraints = {
    batchStatus()
    batchNo(blank:false)
    seqNo()
    allTransactionsCount()
    unProcessedTransactionsSum()
    unProcessedTransactionsCount()
    allTransactionsSum(display:true)
    approvedTransactionsCount()
    approvedTransactionsSum()
    canceledTransactionsCount(display:true)
    canceledTransactionsSum()
    errorTransactionsCount(display:true)
    errorTransactionsSum(display:true)
    declinedTransactionsCount(display:true)
    declinedTransactionsSum(display:true)
    closeTime(nullable:true)
    result(nullable:true)
}


String toString()
{
    return  batchStatus + "-" + batchNo + ":" + seqNo
}

}
```

First Child Class

```
package com.itex.cipg

class ProcessorTxnBatch extends TxnBatch implements Serializable{

/**
*The Server Processor of the Transaction Batch
*
**/
Server server

}
```

The second child Class

```
package com.itex.cipg

class TamsTerminalTxnBatch extends TxnBatch implements Serializable{

/**
*The TAMS Terminal this batch belongs TO
**/
    TamsTerminal terminal
}
```

I will want to add a transaction to the *TamsTerminalTxnBatch* and also to the *ProcessorTxnBatch* Please note `static hasMany = [transactions:transaction]`
After I do

```
def transaction = new Transaction //arbitrarily creating a Transaction
processorTxnBatch.addToTransactions(transaction)
assert processorTxnBatch.transactions.size() = 1 //true
tamsTerminalTxnBatch.addToTransactions(transaction)
assert tamsTerminalTxnBatch.transactions.size() = 1 //true

assert processorTxnBatch.transactions.size() = 0 //true
```

I dont Know Why..........Please Kindly Help me out

Though They are stored on the same Table..........Thanks

Comment: Do you have `table-per-hierarchy` or `table-per-subclass` setup for the child classes?

Comment: All the batches are saved in one Table for both subclass----I did not setup `table-per-hierarchy or table-per-subclass`

Comment: You need to show the actual Domain code.